# I am trying to access previously defined variable sent to snapshot.data? Flutter/Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, http, httprequest

I have made a list/map in a previous page : sideDrawerpage.dart

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> incidentList = [
                    for (final json in listNode.map((x) => x.toJson()))
                      {
                        'Code': json['field'][0]['field_value'],
                        'Description': json['field'][1]['field_value'],
                        'Organisation Unit': json['field'][2]['field_value'],
                        'Date Reported': json['field'][3]['field_value'],
                        'Status': json['field'][4]['field_value'],
                        'RunHyperlink' : json['run_hyperlink']
                      }
                  ];


                  final List<String> values =  [];
                  for(final item in incidentList){
                    String groupedElement = "";
                    for(var innerItem in item.entries)
                    {
                      groupedElement += "${innerItem.key} : ${innerItem.value}\n";
                    }
                    values.add(groupedElement);
                  }

                  await WriteCache.setListString(key: 'cache4', value: values);
```

and it is going through a futurebuilder in another page : lossEvent_page.dart

```
 FutureBuilder(
              future: ReadCache.getStringList(key: 'cache4'),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: ListTile(
                            onTap: () {
                              final hype = jsonEncode(snapshot.data[index]);
                              print(hype);
                            },
                            title: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                              child: Text(snapshot.data[index],
                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                    ),
                                  )),
                            ),
                            tileColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                } else {
                  return const Text("No Data");
                }
              },
            ),
```

My question is : How do I access or use the defined key "RunHyperlink" in the :

```
onTap: () {
final hyperlink = snapshot.data[index];
print(hyperlink);
},
```

Right now it is printing everything in the [index]. I only want to access the RunHyperlink so that I can pass it to another request.

This is what it is printing now :

```
I/flutter (11316): Code : LE-0000000002
I/flutter (11316): Description : test_01
I/flutter (11316): Organisation Unit : 01_01_04_01_SA - Shah Alam
I/flutter (11316): Date Reported : 18/09/2020
I/flutter (11316): Status : LE110 - Pending Approval
I/flutter (11316): RunHyperlink : {classid: 25510, id: 2, mad_key: 32835}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onTap: () {
final hyperlink = snapshot.data[index];
print(hyperlink);
},
```

convert hyperlink variable to Map,
then you can get the value of particular key!